# How to clear a date picker using webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I want to clear and insert a new value in a date picker.
when I use this code, it's just appending the new date with the existing one by default.

here is my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("subheader")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input[1]")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input[1]")).sendKeys("01/01/2013");
```

Thank you
I want to clear and then insert new value for date.

Answer (score -1):

Its case sensitive, use

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input[1]")).Clear();
```

As you have a very long XPath string create a variable to make it easier to read

```
var datePicker = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input[1]"));
datePicker.Clear();
datePicker.SendKeys("01/01/2013");
```

Hope this solves your problem.